# Gnome-shell keeps crashing (logs says :Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 20.04, cuda

I had installed Ubuntu 20.04, which kept crashing randomly. Searching it up on [google](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk02OxB5UgbYTK6ledm4A07pmRVNgkA%3A1604927996979&ei=_EGpX7euO4GW4-EPr8iJiAU&q=ubuntu+crashes+randomly&oq=ubuntu+crashe+randomly&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgAMgYIABAHEB4yCAgAEAgQBxAeOgcIABBHELADUNcUWNYdYMcwaABwAHgAgAGkA4gBnhCSAQkwLjEuNi4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab), tried all the solutions but didn't work.

What I was able to assume is that most common problems point to graphics driver issues.

typing
`sudo dpkg -l nvidia*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                             Version                    Architecture Description
+++-================================-==========================-============-===========================>
un  nvidia-304                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-340                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-384                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-390                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                    <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390         390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-450         450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
un  nvidia-cuda-dev                  <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-cuda-doc                  10.1.243-3                 all          NVIDIA CUDA and OpenCL docu>
ii  nvidia-cuda-gdb                  10.1.243-3                 amd64        NVIDIA CUDA Debugger (GDB)
rc  nvidia-cuda-toolkit              10.1.243-3                 amd64        NVIDIA CUDA development too>
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                  390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
rc  nvidia-dkms-450                  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
un  nvidia-dkms-kernel               <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-driver                    <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-driver-390                390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
un  nvidia-driver-binary             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-common             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390         390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        Shared files used with the >
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-450         450.80.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 amd64        Shared files used with the >
un  nvidia-kernel-source             <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390         390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
un  nvidia-kernel-source-450         <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopencl1                <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev            <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-opencl-dev:amd64          10.1.243-3                 amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL development f>
un  nvidia-opencl-icd                <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-persistenced              <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime                     0.8.14                     all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Pr>
un  nvidia-profiler                  <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-settings                  440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1    amd64        Tool for configuring the NV>
un  nvidia-settings-binary           <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-smi                       <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-tesla-418-driver          <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-tesla-440-driver          <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-utils                     <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-utils-390                 390.138-0ubuntu0.20.04.1   amd64        NVIDIA driver support binar>
un  nvidia-vdpau-driver              <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-visual-profiler           <none>                     <none>       (no description available)
```

so far whenever I have to force restart my system, I always see this error on `/var/log/syslog`

```
**37713b62c32fd,:1.85/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
38086 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System gnome-shell[3673]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freede      sktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
38087 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System dbus-daemon[1047]: [session uid=1000 pid=1047] Successfully activated       service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
38088 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System gsd-media-keys[1494]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settin      gs:playback-random
38089 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System gsd-media-keys[1494]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settin      gs:hibernate
38090 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System gsd-media-keys[1494]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settin      gs:rfkill
38091 Nov  9 18:38:04 aissy-System gsd-media-keys[1494]: Failed to grab accelerator for keybinding settin      gs:playback-repeat**
```

I'm not sure if it's related to this issue of freezing randomly, but it seems that gnome-shell is crashing after this message.

I also reinstalled Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `Graphics:` section from: `inxi -Fxz`? This will provide some additional information that might solve this issue.

Comment: @Matigo, I have the same issue as the OP: https://pastebin.com/Q4je3J2c .
Here is my `inxi -Fxz` output: https://pastebin.com/zAUhDMT1

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep portal` please.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep portal` => https://pastebin.com/HJBJ3uii

Comment: Okay can confirm it in wayland session. Try X11 gnome-session instead.

Comment: Perhaps updating to 20.04?

Comment: I'm not sure. In ubuntu 20.10 error is also present. wfhen I start nautilus in wayland my session is crashing.